# NoSuchMethodError Request.setTag

Tags: java, android, web-services, android-volley

I'm trying to get response from server during register process but app keeps crashing on attempt to get server message. below is the section of the code that makes the request to `AppControlla.java` which in turn passes the request to server.

```
@Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Register Response: " + response.toString());
            hideDialog();
```

and this is the `AppControlla.java`

```
import android.app.Application;
import android.text.TextUtils;

import com.app.myapp.JsonRequestActivity;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.Body;
import retrofit2.http.POST;

import static android.R.attr.tag;

public class AppController extends Application {

public static final String TAG = AppController.class.getSimpleName();

private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

private static AppController mInstance;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mInstance = this;
}

public static synchronized AppController getInstance() {
    return mInstance;
}

public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
    if (mRequestQueue == null) {
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
 }

    return mRequestQueue;
    }

public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
    req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);//crash occurs here
    getRequestQueue().add(req);

}

public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req ) {
    req.setTag(TAG);
    getRequestQueue().add(req);
}

public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
    if (mRequestQueue != null) {
        mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
    }
}
}
```

below is the logcat message

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method setTag(Ljava/lang/Object;)Lcom/android/volley/Request; in class Lcom/android/volley/Request; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.android.volley.Request' appears in /data/app/com.fastchat-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk:classes27.dex) at com.fastchat.AppController.addToRequestQueue(AppController.java:45)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Comment: provide error log information.

Comment: `addToRequestQueue` is never used in your question. Please [edit] with a [mcve]

Comment: @cricket_007 do you want me to add the full `registerProcess` ?

Comment: Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable. Please read the link above.

Comment: Can you give us your volley dependencies ? For example, if you import two packages with the same Class inside, you can have an ambiguity and java cannot resolve method or  class.

Comment: That method definitely exists. Add your gradle file please https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/master/src/main/java/com/android/volley/Request.java#149

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i finally resolved it.the problem was coming from one of my dependencies in my `build.gradle`, i just deleted some of them and the crash stoped.thanks to you guys for the ideas.